# How can I fix the problem of not capturing profile "tools data"? How can I find the profiler service URL?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, profile

I want to use tensorboard to profile my model.
But it shows that the profile "tools data" can't be found.
[image]

My model-profiler, tensorboard and tensorflow version:
model-profiler            1.1.8
tensorboard               2.9.1
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-profile 2.11.2
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1
tensorflow                2.9.1

Then I click the "capture profile" button.
I don't know how to find the profile service URL.
Can anyone help me?
[image: picture that my tensorboard shows no profile data]

I found the [tensorboard profiler website](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/tensorboard.md#set-up-tensorboards-profiler).

BUT it uses docker. I use VScode and I can use tensorboard to show gradients, so does my tensorflow service run correctly?
[image: picture that my tensorbaord can show gradient]